# Authorization for ALB access using Cognito Identity Pool IAM Roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

We are currently working on an authorisation overhaul and have been working to use Cognito to provide this function. We have gotten to the point that API Gateways have been secured using AWS_IAM Authorisation. The Cognito User Pools are based on roles split by groups which with Identity Pool provides an IAM policy in the form of temporary credentials.

However we are also required to secure our ALB backend and only allow users with the relevant permissions to access the resources there. We want this to be as granular as the solutions for API Gateway and S3 (which we also have working and have tested). But we are struggling to solve how to achieve this with ALB as the ALB Authorisation seems to rely on the User Pool rather than the Identity Pool. This is the problem we have as it seems the scopes that a User Pool provide are not granular as all users will receive the same scopes. Is there anyway to authorise access to the ALB resources using the IAM roles provided by the Identity pool instead?